# How to make my editButtonItem work?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Please be toleratant on this as I didn't find anything that helps me clearly.

I would like to allow row deletion in a TableView cells into my app.

I've been suggested to add the following in the viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

**but what's next ?**

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your tableView go in editing mode,

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

You also simply implement the `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method in `UITableViewDelegate`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       [itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}
```

Where `itemList` is simply where you store your data in your `UIViewController`.

Comment: but when clicking on the Edit button I would imagine the tableview would change to edit mode ?

Comment: Yes, you can also swipe to delete

Comment: It doesn't work since when I click on edit the button changes to "Done" which is normal but instead of calling the commitEditingStyle it call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method Also clicking "edit" doesn't show red rounded image on each cell left side

Comment: Thx a lot! +1 do you know any way to show a confirmation box before removing the row?

Comment: Take a look at UIAlertView :  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: Also, make sure you have your UITableViewDelegate set up. You only need to use setEditing:animated if you're NOT subclassing UITableViewController, that is, you're adding a UITableView to a UIViewController.